# Centering canvas context after scaling

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js

I have been trying to use a canvas as a texture in three.js. Since three.js requires textures to be a power of two the canvas width and height is set to [512, 512] however I want the output canvas to be a non-power of two. To keep things scaled I scale the height up by the aspect-ratio, and this moves the center of the objects drawn downwards. I've tried to transform the height back up by some arbitrary numbers ( ie. like `ctx.transform(0, -height/ (1 -(height/width)))` but haven't been able to find the sweet spot. Does anyone know how to handle this?

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, material, ctx, texture, canvas, dimensions;
init();
animate();

function init() {
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
    canvas.width = 512;
    canvas.height = 512;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas)
    
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1);
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
    
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2, 2 );
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
    dimensions = renderer.getSize()
}

function animate() {
  
    ctx.save()
    ctx.scale(1, dimensions.width / dimensions.height)
    // ctx.translate(0, -height * ??);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000"
    ctx.fillRect((canvas.width / 2) - 25, (canvas.height / 2) - 25, 50, 50);
    ctx.restore()
    
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
```

The square is supposed to be scaled (still a square) and centered

Comment: A safer way to do this would be with a second canvas on which you can draw your sprite any size you want. So technically, one square `texture canvas` and one whatever-shape `sprite canvas`. Then simply mash your canvas onto the other one, resizing it in the process. I can't see a square in your snippet regardless to be honest, so I can't see what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. The stackoverflow display is not showing the display correctly in the question, so I put it in a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/m0pnj6de/4/ . I want to scale it to keep the original shapes and positions so I'd want the square to be centered and, well, a square.  The sprite idea might work but I would prefer to keep down the amount of drawcalls if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve your issue by moving to the center and by resizing your renderer every time you draw, so you can see the square remaining square, and by clearing your canvas every draw turn so the multiple draws don't stick around and confuse the position of the square.

```js
function init() {
 
    canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer;
    renderer.setSize( innerWidth, innerHeight);
 
 texture = new THREE.Texture( canvas );
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1 );
    scene = new THREE.Scene;
    
    scene.add( new THREE.Mesh(
     new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2, 2 ),
     new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture })
    ) );
    
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
}
function animate() {
 
 // Always update your renderer size.
 // This might be better off in the window.onresize event.
    renderer.setSize( innerWidth, innerHeight );
    
    // This will clear all draw data from your canvas, so we can draw on an empty canvas
    canvas.width = 512;
    canvas.height = 512;
    
 ctx.save();
    // Move the origin to the center of the canvas
    ctx.translate( canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 );
    // Scale the canvas like you did, except we know the size as we just set it.
    ctx.scale( 1, innerWidth / innerHeight );
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    // Draw the rectangle as if you want its center at the origin
    ctx.fillRect( -25, -25, 50, 50 );
    ctx.restore();
    
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    
}

// I have removed some of the globals we don't need
// as the animate() function only needs access to some.
// I mostly do this because it clarifies what the functions share of resources.
 
var renderer, scene, camera, texture, canvas, ctx;

init();
animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/95/three.min.js"></script>
```

To be honest though, this seems like the inverse of what you are trying to learn about because of how the `OrthographicCamera` works. It is better to set the camera scaled to the viewport instead of your texture (I understand for the purposes this is a decent way of checking your scaling prowess). In this case, your *mesh* is stretched out to an unnatural proportion and your texture corrects it. However, you should probably set your camera and mesh normally and make sure your camera does the right thing and scales to your viewport (just like the `.aspect` value on a `PerspectiveCamera` will show you the correct visual)

```js
function dispatch_draw( time ){
  
  window.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent( 'draw' ) );
 
 window.requestAnimationFrame( dispatch_draw );
 
}
function event_draw(){

 renderer.render( scene, camera );
 
}
function event_resize(){
 
 dimensions.set( innerWidth, innerHeight );
 renderer.setSize( dimensions.x, dimensions.y );
 
 camera.left = -dimensions.x / 2;
 camera.right = dimensions.x / 2;
 camera.top = dimensions.y / 2;
 camera.bottom = -dimensions.y / 2;
 camera.near = -1;
 camera.far = 1;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

}

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer;
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera;
const scene = new THREE.Scene;
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
 new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 200, 200 ),
 new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 })
);
const dimensions = new THREE.Vector2( innerWidth, innerHeight );

scene.add( mesh );

window.addEventListener( 'resize', event_resize );
window.addEventListener( 'draw', event_draw );

event_resize();
dispatch_draw();

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/95/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response but thanks for the answer, a lot of good info in there